# How to retrieve the URLs that are being visited by the PC currently. Or, that are requested for

Tags: vb.net

My Target is to make a program that will prevent users on my PC to navigate on some websites.

Comment: Please show an attempt at what you have tried and where you are stuck...

Answer (score 0):

To monitor http traffic, you can use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

If you want to write on your own code, you can utilize [Fiddler Core](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore). Refer this [sample](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore-demo2).

However, there are simple ways to block websites without need to code, such as by [editing hosts](http://www.wikihow.com/Block-a-Website-in-All-Web-Browsers), etc.

Comment: Good information. On another note, the host file is unreliable as it's easy to change and isn't reliable in many cases.

Comment: That was a great piece of info. It could do the trick, but i actually need to detect the event that denies the navigation so that i can raise a message to te user that the navigation has been restricted!